# Microsoft Access 2007 with VBA - Parse Textbox, vbCrLf delimited

Tags: vba, character, csv

Through some cruel twist of fate I have landed a job maintaining a system built entirely on Microsoft Access 2007.

Anyway, I have a TextBox on a Form. I want to parse the contents of this TextBox. I want to declare two strings, have string one equal to the first line of the TextBox, string two equal to the second line and so on.

I think I need to something similiar to below but I can't quite get my head around it.

Thanks

John

```
Dim stringOne As String
Dim stringTwo As String

Dim contentsOfTextBox As Array

contentsOfTextBox = Split("txtMyTextBox.Text", "vbCrLf")

stringOne = contentsOfTextBox[0].Text
stringTwo = contentsOfTextBox[1].Text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean

```
contentsOfTextBox = Split(Me.txtMyTextBox, vbCrLf)

stringOne = contentsOfTextBox(0)
stringTwo = contentsOfTextBox(1)
```

However, this looks like it may be leading to an awkward idea. It may be best to describe the real world problem you wish to solve with this.